# Get the Number of Keys on Keyboard C#

Tags: c#, wpf, for-loop, keyboard, key

I was trying to List all Keys in a WPF ListBox:

```
foreach (Key key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key)))
            {
                lb.Items.Add(key.ToString());
            }
```

But this didn't return the Keys (A,...,Escape,Enter). It returned None,Cancel,Back,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using pure XAML

```
...
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="KeysValues" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type system:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="Key"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource KeysValues}}"/>
</Grid>
...
```

Comment: As you can see in my answer, some `enum` Keys have non-unique numeric values. As result, `.ToString()` returns same name for some Keys e.g. `Return` will be repeated twice. Thus, the output will be different from the actual `Key` names.

Comment: @If you want to return the enum names instead of enum values, simply change `MethodName="GetValues"` to `MethodName="GetNames"`

Answer (score 2):

You can get `enum` names instead of values

```csharp
foreach (string key in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Key)))
{
    lb.Items.Add(key);
}
```

---

Or you can display combined names and values. Something like Metadata that Visual Studio shows.

```csharp
System.Collections.IEnumerator keys = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key)).GetEnumerator();
foreach (string key in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Key)))
{
    keys.MoveNext();
    lb.Items.Add(key + " = " + (int)keys.Current);
}
```

[image]

Comment: i would like to list A,B,C,leftShift,Enter,LeftControl,numP5,F1... and not  cancel,next,execute

Comment: @MusicGrotesqueTV you can create a collection with not needed keys and exclude it from adding to the list.